# SSSD and autofs

Tags: centos, autofs, sssd

I am trying to set up SSSD to get automount maps from Active Directory.

I think my settings are correct but it uses the wrong username to query AD.
It takes whatever that is set as "mapname" (behind the `+` sign) from `/etc/auto.master`, for example `+auto.master` results in the following debug log (sssd_autofs debug_level=6):

```
[sssd[autofs]] [accept_fd_handler] (0x0400): Client connected!
[sssd[autofs]] [sss_cmd_get_version] (0x0200): Received client version [1].
[sssd[autofs]] [sss_cmd_get_version] (0x0200): Offered version [1].
[sssd[autofs]] [sss_autofs_cmd_setautomntent] (0x0400): Got request for automount map named auto.master@example.com
[sssd[autofs]] [sss_parse_name_for_domains] (0x0200): name 'auto.master@example.com' matched expression for domain 'example.com', user is auto.master
[sssd[autofs]] [setautomntent_send] (0x0400): Requesting info for automount map [auto.master] from [example.com]
[sssd[autofs]] [lookup_automntmap_step] (0x0400): Requesting info for [auto.master@example.com]
[sssd[autofs]] [sysdb_get_map_byname] (0x0400): No such map
[sssd[autofs]] [lookup_automntmap_step] (0x0080): No automount map [auto.master] in cache for domain [example.com]
[sssd[autofs]] [sss_dp_issue_request] (0x0400): Issuing request for [0x406840:0:auto.master@example.com]
[sssd[autofs]] [sss_dp_get_autofs_msg] (0x0400): Creating autofs request for [example.com][4105][mapname=auto.master]
[sssd[autofs]] [sss_dp_internal_get_send] (0x0400): Entering request [0x406840:0:auto.master@example.com]
[sssd[autofs]] [lookup_automntmap_step] (0x0400): Requesting info for [auto.master@example.com]
[sssd[autofs]] [sysdb_autofs_entries_by_map] (0x0400): Getting entries for map auto.master
[sssd[autofs]] [sysdb_autofs_entries_by_map] (0x0400): No entries for the map
[sssd[autofs]] [lookup_automntmap_step] (0x0400): setautomntent done for map auto.master
[sssd[autofs]] [sss_autofs_cmd_setautomntent_done] (0x0400): setautomntent found data
[sssd[autofs]] [sss_dp_req_destructor] (0x0400): Deleting request: [0x406840:0:auto.master@example.com]
[sssd[autofs]] [sss_autofs_cmd_getautomntent] (0x0400): Requested data of map auto.master@example.com cursor 0 max entries 512
[sssd[autofs]] [sss_autofs_cmd_getautomntent] (0x0400): Performing implicit setautomntent
[sssd[autofs]] [sss_parse_name_for_domains] (0x0200): name 'auto.master@example.com' matched expression for domain 'example.com', user is auto.master
[sssd[autofs]] [setautomntent_send] (0x0400): Requesting info for automount map [auto.master] from [example.com]
[sssd[autofs]] [lookup_automntmap_step] (0x0400): Requesting info for [auto.master@example.com]
[sssd[autofs]] [sss_dp_issue_request] (0x0400): Issuing request for [0x406840:0:auto.master@example.com]
[sssd[autofs]] [sss_dp_get_autofs_msg] (0x0400): Creating autofs request for [example.com][4105][mapname=auto.master]
[sssd[autofs]] [sss_dp_internal_get_send] (0x0400): Entering request [0x406840:0:auto.master@example.com]
[sssd[autofs]] [lookup_automntmap_step] (0x0400): Requesting info for [auto.master@example.com]
[sssd[autofs]] [sysdb_autofs_entries_by_map] (0x0400): Getting entries for map auto.master
[sssd[autofs]] [sysdb_autofs_entries_by_map] (0x0400): No entries for the map
[sssd[autofs]] [lookup_automntmap_step] (0x0400): setautomntent done for map auto.master
[sssd[autofs]] [getautomntent_implicit_done] (0x0020): Cannot get map after setautomntent succeeded?
[sssd[autofs]] [sss_dp_req_destructor] (0x0400): Deleting request: [0x406840:0:auto.master@example.com]
[sssd[autofs]] [sss_autofs_cmd_endautomntent] (0x0400): endautomntent called
[sssd[autofs]] [client_recv] (0x0200): Client disconnected!
```

Anyone got this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found some help on the #sssd IRC channel.

Apparently the `user is` log entry does not mean the user connecting, but just the automount map it is looking for.

It appeared I had a misconfiguration on AD.
By raising the domain `debug_level` to 6 in my sssd.conf as follows:

```
...
[domain/example.com]
debug_level = 6
...
```

I was able to view the LDAP query made to my AD server.
It appears I had to place my nisObjects under my nisMap's, I had them placed in the same OU=automount.

So I moved these objects and all is working fine now!